# Display Wordpress posts with tags same as name of current post

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, tags

How could I display wordpress posts with a tag that matches the title of current post. For example the current post is titled "Jaguar". After the jaguar content displays I want any posts tagged with  the word "Jaguar" to to show below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get all the posts that tagged with the particular word.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag='.get_the_title() );
```

Link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters